# Is there any possibility to update facebook and twitter details from user application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed one web application which will export and import profile details to other application.Let me know the possibilities available in facebook and twitter for profile importing.

Thanks in advance,
Ruthra V

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/) and [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/) APIs? Or the documentation for whatever wrapper/library you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I already went through the APIs of facebook and twitter but I couldn't find anything.If you find any,Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes go and have a look at Pete Brown's fishbowl projects.

http://10rem.net/blog/2009/11/22/fishbowl-a-wpf-front-end-for-facebook-with-full-source

Comment: Hi Alski thanks for your response,Is there any API available for exporting profile information from our application to twitter or facebook?

Comment: I regret it's a while since I looked through the FishBowl code. I'm pretty sure it was in there.  Also, I'm pretty sure that twitter profile changes are available through http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/